# How to detect FILE name and LINE of last php execution point statement?

Tags: php, reflection, exit

I see white screen.

Somewhere my php script finished its execution.

There are no php errors or warnings.
There is a lot of framework files to go through var_dump to detect place, where the script die.

Likely, some of Framework file calls die() or exit.

How can I detect last php statement? (FILE and LINE)

The statement for PHP which finished its execution without going though endless files and endless
`var_dump`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your PHP file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

More information on what this does can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-errors-in-php-file)

Comment: Hmm, then I would guess something like `debug_backtrace()` would be your best bet...  Usage info [here](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/19/8/8/backtracing-your-code)